# Как открыть файл.txt как массив символов, чтобы изменить текстовый документ?

Tags: массивы, c, символы

Как вообще можно изменить текстовой документ на Си (без плюсов)? Думаю, надо, чтобы он был как массив символов? Посоветуете что-нибудь... **Я совсем новичок...**

Задача у меня такая:

> написать простую программу которая удаляет (1)цифры и точку в начале каждой строки если есть, (2)удаляет символы 'A',')',(3) удаляет символ '\n' перед 'A)'. Например, у меня:
>
> 1. Choose the right variant. “They … at seven o’clock”
>
> A) get up
>
> 1. Choose the synonym. «a time-table»:
>
> А) a schedule

Результат должен быть примерно таким:

```
Choose the synonym. «a time-table»: a schedule
Choose the right variant. “They … at seven o’clock” get up
```

Comment: смотря, что понимать под словом "модифицировать".

 - Удалит пару строк: открываем файл, построчно читаем. Если строка подходит - пишем в второй(временный файл), если нет - пропускаем. В конце один файл удаляем, второй переименовываем.
 - Заменить пару слов. Аналогично предыдущему, только в файл записываем модифицированную строку.

Comment: Опишите вашу задачу на более высоком уровне. Что именно вы хотите сделать с файлом?

Comment: @Дато, вот с разбивкой примера на строки у Вас в комментарии что-то не задалось...

Видимо в такой задаче надо читать файл построчно (весь в память читать **не надо**), и выводить результаты в другой файл. После окончания просто сделайте `rename()`.

Теперь об обработке.

Не очень понятно, что делать, если *после* удаляемых цифр и точки идет текст "A)"??? Надо ли его объединять с предыдущей строкой?

МЕСТА МАЛО, поэтому продолжу в **UPDATE** своего ответа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если размер увеличиваться не будет, то самое простое, это открыть файл на чтение-запись (`man fopen`, mode "r+"), прочесть длину файла (`man fseek, man ftell`), выделить кусок памяти нужного размера (`man malloc`) и прочесть весь файл (`man fread`) в него.

Затем изменить байты в памяти, как Вам требуется, спозиционироваться в начало файла (`man fseek или rewind`) и записать измененный файл (`man fwrite`).

Правда надо отметить, что обычно такое редактирование текста не очень эффективно. Обычно текстовый файл это последовательность строк и Вы редактируете его, основываясь на такой структуре.

Часто текстовый файл в памяти представляют в виде *списка* строк. Не знаю, знакомы ли Вы с такой структурой данных, если еще нет, то советую изучить.

Каждая строка это отдельный кусок памяти. С этим куском связывают указатель на следующий, а часто и на предыдущий, что позволяет легко удалять строки и включать новые. Тут же разумно хранить размер строки (сколько байт выделено) и ее текущую длину.
Вставка и удаление символов в рамках одной строки значительно эффективней, чем для одного массива символов в котором находится весь файл.

Вообще, детали редактирования можно обсудить позже.

Правда, доступ по номеру строки для такой структуры данных требует (обычно) последовательного перебора строк.

В подобном случае лучше организовать чтение-запись несколько по другому. Открываете файл на чтение (`fopen`), считываете его в цикле по строкам (рекомендую функцию `getline` из GNU, в этом случае можно сразу получать строки выделенные `malloc`), в этом же цикле строите список строк.

По концу файла закрываете его и переходите к своему редактированию в память.

Для записи - открываете файл на запись (при этом его размер автоматически урежется до нуля), в цикле пробегаете по списку строк и пишете содержимое каждой (`man fputs`) в файл. Закрываете его. Все готово.

Рекомендую осваивать все это в *nix (например в Linux).

**UPDATE** после комментария [[@Дато](/users/12200/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE)](/users/12200/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE) c объяснением сути редактирования.

Видимо в такой задаче надо читать файл построчно (весь в память читать **не надо**), и выводить результаты в другой файл. После окончания просто сделайте `rename()`.

Теперь об обработке.

Не очень понятно, что делать, если *после* удаляемых цифр и точки идет текст "A)"?
Надо ли его объединять с предыдущей строкой?

--

Но, в любом случае идея такая.

В цикле построчно читаете входной файл.

Ищете в прочитанной строке удаляемое начало (strspn() + strncmp()). Анализируете, надо ли убрать '\n' в предыдущей строке. Если да, смещаетесь в выводимом файле (`fseek`) на символ назад (это и будет '\n' предыдущей строки, который Вам надо удалить).

Естественно, в общем случае надо отслеживать текущую позицию записи и для нулевой шаг назад не делать.

Пишите в выходной файл строку начиная с символа **после** этого "удаления".

Comment: @avp ну если человеку хочется файл как массив символов, то mmap() ему в руки.

Comment: @alexlz, моя первая мысль была именно такой. Но потом я подумал, если человек предупреждает, что он *совсем новичок*, то `mmap()` будет выглядеть просто издевательством.